# Update location every 5sec android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

Hi I want get user location for every 5sec and user can change that duration like 10sec, 15sec upto 30sec i have spinner to choose this option

this is my request

```
 private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
        .setInterval(5000) // 5 seconds
        .setFastestInterval(16) // 16ms = 60fps
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

this is initiate my start update

```
 private void startPeriodicUpdates(int intervel) {
    stopPeriodicUpdates();
    REQUEST.setInterval(intervel);
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(REQUEST, this);
    // mConnectionState.setText(R.string.location_requested);
}
```

I can pass user selected interval to startPeriodicUpdates() method like startPeriodicUpdates(5000), startPeriodicUpdates(15000). But they location update duration working fine 15sec and more than 15sec
If i give 5sec or 10 sec the location update is running for every second

```
06-18 18:46:23.638: I/Location(2860): Location Changed Location[fused 65.966697,-18.533300 acc=4 et=+1h0m13s881ms alt=15.044444]
06-18 18:46:24.642: I/Location(2860): Location Changed Location[fused   65.966697,-18.533300 acc=4 et=+1h0m14s883ms alt=15.044444]
06-18 18:46:25.642: I/Location(2860): Location Changed Location[fused 65.966697,-18.533300 acc=4 et=+1h0m15s883ms alt=15.044444]
```

log show time interval for 23, 24, 25 please give your ideas.

Comment: are you using service in background?

Comment: for that you need to every time register locationlistner but it 0 to 30-40 will not update location it take littlebit time

Comment: @DevilAbhi no its in activity only.

Comment: @PankajAndroid yes i m register every time. it update. my question was 5 second and 10 second intervel update duration was wrong its update each second but above 15second working fine. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setInterval` method is not exact.  [This is mentioned in the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setInterval%28long%29)

Also, use the same interval for `setFastestInterval` and `setInterval` to prevent your app from receiving location updates faster than the the interval you specified in `setInterval`.

Just add `REQUEST.setFastestInterval(intervel);` to your `startPeriodicUpdates` method.