# How to make the default Google Maps current location icon smoother

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've looked through a lot of documentation and questions asked here on stack overflow (for instance [How to smoothly keep moving current location marker in Google Maps v2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091591/how-to-smoothly-keep-moving-current-location-marker-in-google-maps-v2-android) and [Android Maps API v2 Change MyLocation Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826345/android-maps-api-v2-change-mylocation-icon/19651535#19651535)) but haven't found any answer if it's possible to make the default current location icon (see attached image) moving smoother when tracking current location (while moving around). I have played around with how often the requestLocationUpdates should trigger (time and distance) but nothing will make it move nicer across the map.

I have no problem creating a marker and make that one smoother, but I don't know how to get hold of the blue icon. It doesn't seem to be a marker at all?

Is it possible to make it smoother, or do I have to set

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

and implement my own current location marker?

[image: current location icon]

Answer (score 0):

The [Receiving Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates) in the Android training documentation discusses using `LocationListener` to get interval updates. You set the LocationRequest and set its interval (either `setFastestInterval` or `setInterval`) to get timely updates that you want. This can, however, affect battery consumption if your updates are too frequent.

Other raised issues similar to yours is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286678/update-location-every-5sec-android) ticket. Hoping you can get additional information for your case here.